# FFmpeg NaCl module avformat_open_input (on rtsp stream) returns -5: I/O error

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, google-nativeclient, rtsp-client

I want to create an RTSP player in Chrome PNaCl.

I have successfully built the ffmpeg naclport including the following networking flags in the **build.sh** file for the ffmpeg NaCl port.

*--enable network --enable-protocols --enable-demuxer=rtsp --enable-demux=rtp --enable-demuxer=sdp --enable-decoder=h264*

Furthermore, I have successfully coded and the linked the ffmpeg NaCl port in my own PNaCl module. I have included the following network permissions in the manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [
{
    "socket": [
        "tcp-listen:*:*", 
        "tcp-connect:*:*", 
        "resolve-host:*:*", 
        "udp-bind:*:*", 
        "udp-send-to:*:*"
    ],
}
```

Now once I run the following code, in PNaCl, the **avformat_open_input(...) returns -5 or I/O Error**:

```
    AVFormatContext* formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    av_register_all();

    avformat_network_init();

    const char * stream_path = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";

    int result = avformat_open_input(&formatContext, stream_path ,NULL,NULL);

    if(result< 0){

        PostMessage("input not opened, result: ");

        PostMessage(result);

    }else{

      PostMessage(std::string("input successfully opened"));

    }
```

What am I possibly doing wrong, and why can't the PNaCl module access the RTSP stream?

*PS. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854270/avformat-open-input-return-value-error-code-on-nacl-module) is a similar question, but it gives no definitive answer.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `avformat_open_input` from your main thread?  It seems like socket operations are blocked from working in the main thread.

Try moving your code to a background thread or, better yet, use ppapi_simple as this automatically executes your code in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done that using ppapi, now the error becomes **Invalid data input**. Many say that this is a bug in internals of NaCl FFmpeg port. Is this true?

Comment: Is there an example which uses the c++ version of ppapi_simple?

Comment: Why doing `avformat_open_input` in a new thread still gives the same error?

Comment: @Taimoor Alam do you mind sharing some parts of your code, I am building a screen recorder using ffmepg with nacl but confused where to start