# PNACL: C++ style implementation of ppapi_simple?

Tags: c++, google-nativeclient

I need to work in ppapi_simple implementation in C++ because I need the code to work in background thread.

`ps.h` file in NACL sdk explains:

> For C++ style development, use the ppapi_simple_instance.h,
>   ppapi_simple_instance_2d.h, and ppapi_simple_instance_3d.h headers as
>   a base class, and overload the appropriate virtual functions such as
>   Main, ChangeContext, or Render.

I cannot find the `ppapi_simple_instance.h`, `ppapi_simple_instance2d.h` and `ppapi_simple_3d.h` as suggested in ps.h?

Moreover, where can I find examples to understand and implement this concept? Is there a ppapi_simple video_decode example available?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610191/ffmpeg-nacl-module-avformat-open-input-on-rtsp-stream-returns-5-i-o-error) it is suggested to use `avformat_open_input` in background thread OR use `ppapi_simple`. Using new thread does not solve it and there are no C++ style header files as mentioned in `ps.h`